# In Javascript, how do I map an array where elements could split into multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an object like this:

```
var families =
[
    { dad: 'bob', mom: 'sue', income: 10 },
    { dad: 'john', mom: 'jane', income: 5 }
];
```

Is there a fancy way to transform this into the following:

```
[ 'bob', 'sue', 'john', 'jane' ];
```

I know I could do it like this:

```
var people = [];
for (var index = 0; index < families.length; index++)
{
    people.push(families[index].dad);
    people.push(families[index].mom);
}
```

However I like to use Javascript's build-in array functions whenever possible (filter, map, forEach, etc). The best I could figure is using 'map':

```
var people = families.map(function(family)
{
    return [family.dad, family.mom];
});
```

But that doesn't do what I want:

```
[ [ 'bob', 'sue' ], [ 'john', 'jane' ] ]
```

Is there any built-in that can do what I want? Thanks!

Comment: Use a `.flat()` at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destructure the properties out in the `.map`, return an array like you're doing, then `.flat()`ten the array:

```js
var families = [
    { dad: 'bob', mom: 'sue', income: 10 },
    { dad: 'john', mom: 'jane', income: 5 }
];

const names = families
  .map(({ dad, mom }) => [dad, mom])
  .flat();
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

```js
let families =
[
    { dad: 'bob', mom: 'sue', income: 10 },
    { dad: 'john', mom: 'jane', income: 5 }
];

const result = families.reduce((res, item)=> {
return [...res, item.dad, item.mom]
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Or just add [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)() funtion to map result:

```
var people = families.map(function(family)
{
    return [family.dad, family.mom];
}).flat();
```

Answer (score 0):

- One line code using .map
- Creating nested array and then using .flat

```js
var families =
[
    { dad: 'bob', mom: 'sue', income: 10 },
    { dad: 'john', mom: 'jane', income: 5 }
];

console.log (families.map(it => [it.dad, it.mom]).flat())
```